# Нужна ли запятая в предложении: "Брось(,) и бежим!"?

Tags: пунктуация

Это ведь сложносочиненное предложение с двумя сказуемыми, так? Мне кажется, что запятая нужна, но примера не нашла.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Нужна запятая.

*[Ты] брось, и [мы] бежим!* || Ещё вторая часть как бы является следствием первой (*бросай, и тогда мы побежим*).

Для отсутствия запятой нужно единое согласование глаголов:
*Бросаем и бежим.*

Comment: Вот я так и подумала, только объяснить не могла. Стала наспех искать в интернете и нашла несколько вариантов без запятой (не правила с обоснованиями, а просто, скажем так, авторская пунктуация). Пришла в замешательство, решила тут уточнить. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Всё не так просто. "Брось" - это повелительное наклонение. "Бежим" при повелительной интонации - это тоже повелительное наклонение (призыв к совместному действию). То есть два повелительных наклонения тут, и оба выражают побуждение к действию.

Чаще всего говорят, что повелительное наклонение без подлежащего - это полное односоставное определённо-личное предложение. У Валгиной применительно к такого рода предложениям (полным односоставным) даже термин "сказуемое" не используется. То есть "Брось" - это предложение, "Бежим" - это предложение. Это во-первых.

Во-вторых, у той же Валгиной есть точка зрения, что два определённо-личных предложения с союзом и - это не однородные сказуемые, а именно что два простых предложения в составе сложного, в вашем случае сложносочинённого. То есть сочетание "Брось и бежим!" можно представить как сложносочинённое предложение, состоящее из двух простых определённо-личных предложений, причём побудительных.

А дальше обращаемся к Розенталю и Лопатину — с их известным замечанием о том, что "запятая перед союзами *и, да* (в значении «и»), *или* либо не ставится, если части сложносочиненного предложения... выражены двумя побудительными предложениями".

Стало быть, не преступлением будет и так написать: ***Брось и Бежим!***

Про единое согласование глаголов - это субъективно.

Вот примеры без запятой и без согласования:

> А теперь, Рупрехт, *бери свою чернильницу и идём в монастырь*: сейчас
>   начнётся допрос твоей Ренаты (Брюсов).

---

> Тебя сейчас возьмут. *Надень парик и бежим* (Аксёнов).

Comment: Есть над чем подумать. Спасибо.

Comment: В примерах Розенталя части равноправны и их можно без проблем поменять местами. Но не в нашем примере. В вашем первом примере общий элемент "А теперь, Рупрехт". Второй пример не обоснован. Автор решил не ставить запятую вследствие отсутствия паузы, игнорируя грамматику.

Comment: Я, кхм, не могу проникнуть в мозги Аксёнову и узнать оттуда, что он там решил и почему. Не факт, что он вообще грамматику знал. В любом случае его произведения правили издательские корректоры, и они, как видите, "игнорируя грамматику", взяли да и допустили отсутствие запятой. Стало быть, по их мнению, всё нормально. Или сам автор на этом настоял. Может быть. Но я с этим согласен. Первый пример аналогичен, там и без общего обращения можно не ставить запятую из-за общей побудительности. Про мену местами и прочее - это уже всё субъективно.

Comment: Хотя, я не спорю, что возможны и запятая, конечно, и даже тире. В корпусе есть примеры с тире. Однако можно и без них.